# Android 4 bars size(Galaxy Nexus)

Tags: android, size, screen, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, galaxy-nexus

What are the sizes of Status Bar, Navigation Bar and Title Bar in pixels in galaxy nexus?

I think its because of them that my background image(720x1280 px) is getting with height stretched.

My layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/splash" >
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? http://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html

Navigation Bar and Action Bar have a height (or width) of 48dp.

If you want to remove everything (except the buttons), you can add this in the declaration of your activity in the manifest

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Comment: Actually i need their size in pixels to make backgrounds in photoshop at the correct size, but the dp size helped,  thanks a lot.
And Status Bar size have idea?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the Nexus 7 tablet running Android 4.1, the nav bar at the bottom appears visually to be significantly deeper than the 48 pixels described in the dev guide linked in the message above. Analysing a screengrab suggests that the new nav bar is 75 px in portrait. I'm still hunting for the definitive measurement.

Answer (score 0):

48 dp is not the same than 48 px. 48 dps for a xhdpi / normal screen device like Nexus is the same than 96px.